# Как переделать функциональный компонент Modal в классовый компонент?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть код в котором один функциональный компонент а также один классовый компонент. Хочу сделать так чтобы были только классовые компоненты но мне никогда не приходилось работать с функциональными компонентами поэтому я не могу перевести их в классовый.
Как переделать функциональный компонент Modal и его return в классовый компонент?

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const onClick = e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('close') || !e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
      props.close();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal" onClick={onClick}>
      <div className="modal-content">
        <span className="close">&times;</span>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Весь код:
https://jsfiddle.net/nathan111777/ftpbv8ms/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yx7eu9jd/) исходя из того что вы предоставили

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const onClick = e => {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('close') || !e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
        this.props.close();
      }
    }
    return(
      <div className="modal" {...{onClick}}>
        <div className="modal-content">
          <span className="close">&times;</span>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: добавил в код, не работает:
https://jsfiddle.net/nathan111777/ftpbv8ms/10/

Comment: @vrm111 обновил пример попробуйте

Comment: спасибо) работает) а вы в хуках разбираетесь?)

Comment: @vrm111 всегда пожалуйста .Да разбираюсь но это уже  тема не для этого вопроса.

Comment: хочу у вас спросить как в одной части другого кода убрать хуки, создать новую тему или сбросить вам песочницу сюда в коментарии?

Comment: @vrm111 напишите новый вопрос   сегодня уже не успею завтра гляну.Если не ответят до меня помогу чем смогу.

Comment: ок, благодарю))

Answer (score 1):

Хочу предложить вот такой ответ. Я немного видоизменил ваш код, появился еще один `div`, зато больше не нужно производить никакие махинации с `event.target`.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { close, children } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal-overlay" onClick={close} />
        <div className="modal-content">
          <span className="close" onClick={close}>&times;</span>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Полный пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0ajkw6t/1/)

Comment: спасибо огромное!